# How I can use a Session for a long time in my ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, browser

I have a ASP.NET Application where I use Sessions. In this Session I get the language for Example.

Example:

```
Session["language"] = language;
```

And in a other Area in my Code I use then...

```
language = Session["language"].toString();
```

It works fine but the user had open the Browser about a feu Hours in the Background with the Application then the Session don't work :(

Why it doesn't work and how I can solve this Problem.

Comment: change your session expiration time. I guess it's set to 20 minutes by default. Look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options either to use [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or to increase session timeout setting.

You can increase the session timeout by increasing timeout in the `web.config`.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  ...
   <sessionState timeout="90" />
  ...
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In my opinion using cookies is a better approach.

> [Beginners Guide To ASP NET Cookies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies)

Comment: I read I can do this in the IIS7 Configuration, too. is the 90 for minutes?

Comment: Yes . <sessionState timeout="time in minutes" />

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you save the value in a cookie.